# Why features compression is good?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'm reading about deep learning and that in principles it's a features compression technique and that is why it works. Now my question is why compressing features from 200 or so into 4 is better? How and why does it influence classifiers performance or the construction of the decision boundary?

Look at the following picture for example:
[image]

Assume that blue points are class-0 and red points are class-1.

A classifier might see that any instance that has an $x_2$ lower than $0.5$ is of class-0 and any instance that has $x_2$ above $0.5$ is class-1. At this time $x_1$ is redundant.

But now look at this example:

[image]

In this example $x_1$ becomes vital for a good performance.

So why features compression is better? Or could (if not always better) lead to a better performance?

Answer (score 2):

Feature compression is usually better when some features provide no additional information: the information they provide is already provided by other features, or the feature is basically noise. If every feature is useful you don't need to reduce dimensionality, generally. However, depending on your algorithm, too many features might make the model practically to slow, you have to reduce features. Also, having too many features could lead to overfitting problems.